# Is there a way to check when something is added to a list like "a=[]"

Tags: python

I want to print something whenever something is added to a list that I've defined earlier in the code. How do I go about doing this?

```py
a = []
```

Couldn't find anything on Google about this

Comment: I don't think there is any built-in way to do this. You would need to implement a getter/setter for the list to manually monitor it.

Comment: just check if new list is the same as original list?

Comment: You would just need to check the list after each addition.

Answer (score 5):

There's no built-in way to do this, but you can very easily make your list a user-defined class inheriting from `list` and hook into the append method:

```
class MyList(list): 
    def append(self, item): 
        print(f'item {item} will be appended to {str(self)}') 
        return_value = super().append(item) 
        print(f'append succeeded -> list is now {str(self)}') 
        return return_value

mylist = MyList('abc')

print(mylist)
# output:
# ['a', 'b', 'c']

mylist.append('d')
# output:
# item d will be appended to ['a', 'b', 'c']
# append succeeded -> list is now ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

print(mylist)
# output:
# ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```